# Is doing an AngularJS component that takes a complicated config input a good approach?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

This is an angularjs component I made to populate the material's md-menu:

```
<link  href="./components/base-components/ellipsis-menu/ellipsis.css" 
       rel="stylesheet">

<md-menu >                                                
    <md-button aria-label="Open phone interactions menu"
               class="md-icon-button"
               ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdMenu, $event,$index)">
        <md-icon   md-font-icon="fa fa-ellipsis-v"
                   style="color: rgb(189, 187, 187);">
        </md-icon>
    </md-button>    
    <md-menu-content width="4">
        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in ctrl.functionsArray.arr">         
            <md-button ng-click="ctrl.click(item.function, item.args)" >
                <md-icon md-font-icon="{{item.icon}}"
                         ng-style="item.style"   
                         md-menu-align-target="">
                </md-icon>
                {{item.label}}  
            </md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

and JS:

```
function eCtrl($scope,$mdMenu) {     

    this.openMenu = function ($mdMenu, ev) {
        originatorEv = ev;
        $mdMenu.open(ev);
    };

}


angular.
    module('clientApp').
    component('appEllipsis', {
        templateUrl: 'components/base-components//ellipsis-menu/ellipsis.html',
        controller: eCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',            
        bindings: {
            functionsArray:"<", //{arr:[{label:'', function:'',args:'', icon:'', style:'color: black;'},..etc]},    
    }
});
```

So its usage would be something like:

```
<app-ellipsis functions-array="{
                arr:[{
                   function:ctrl.openAcceptConfirm,
                   icon:'fa fa-check',
                   args:[$event,offer._id],
                   label: 'Accept',
                   style:{'color': 'green'}
                 },{
                   function:ctrl.openRejectConfirmObligor,
                   icon:'fa fa-times',
                   args:[$event, offer._id],
                   label: 'Reject',
                   style:{'color': 'red'}
                }]}"
></app-ellipsis>
```

So it's taking an input, which is an array of objects, each that contains a function, arguments of function, icon class, label and color. That's the only component I did that takes a such long json config (usually I prefer to use one-value bindings).
Note that this long config could be written into a variable in the parent's controller to make the above neater.

My coworker said it's a bad practice thing,  since in his opinion, "the logic is inside styling; and not separating logic, from content, from design" in this component (which I didn't get much what that means).

He would prefer to use ngTransclude instead; but I think using ngTransclude would make its html syntax deployment as long as if not using a component.

I have seen many components that take "complicated configuration" as input while their html selector (usage) is short, like the Angular's ng2-smart table: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation

So from pure good/bad practice perspectives, what's bad in the approach above? And what's the better alternative? (And why)

Comment: If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view. With `$event`, give it a different name because it can be confused with [AngularJS's `$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', ["clientId", "planetName", function DemoController(clientId, planetName) {
  this.clientId = clientId;
  this.planetName = planetName;
}]);
```

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
   Client ID: {{demo.clientId}}
   <br>
   Planet Name: {{demo.planetName}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?